# Is there a way to programmatically launch samsung's device "unmonitored apps" from my app?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, xiaomi, samsung

I know this method:
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setPackage("com.samsung.android.lool."));`

But with this method, I can only go to the device maintenance section. Where I want to go with one touch is the "unmonitored apps" section.

Do you know a code that I can write instead of `"com.samsung.android.lool"` to go to the "unmonitored apps" section?

Also for xiaomi and huawei phones does anyone know a valid code where I can go to the "unmonitored apps" section?